# Complex SQL query assistance

Tags: sql

I have a DB that contains informations about buses arriving to/departing from a station. In my application, I need to display all departures from the station that the user selects.

That means that I have to identify each line that passes trough the selected station. I did that with the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LinePaths.TimetableID 
               ,Lines.LineName AS [Line]
               ,Timetable.Heading
               ,LinePaths.Departure
               ,Regime.Name AS [Regime]
FROM            LinePaths
INNER JOIN Timetables ON Timetables.TimetableID = LinePaths.TimetableID
INNER JOIN Lines ON Timetable.LineID = Lines.LineID
INNER JOIN Stations ON LinePaths.Station = Station.StationID
INNER JOIN Regimes ON Timetables.Regime = Regimes.RegimeID
WHERE Station = @Station
```

The problem is that instead of `Timetable.Heading` I need to display the name of the final station that the bus is heading to. These are the schema's of the tables I have at my disposal:

- `Stations - ID, Name`
- `Lines - LineID, LineName`
- `Timetable - TimetableID, LineID, Heading, Regime`  (`Regime` defines on which days the bus drives)
- `LinePaths - ID, TimetableID, SN, Arrival, Departure, StationID` (The `SN` is a serial number that defines the order of stations on a certain paths (the bus will arrive to those stations in that particular order).)

So, instead of the `Timetable.Heading` I need to have a `Stations.Name`, and here I come to my problem.

That column has to represent the final station to which the bus is going (for every line), so I have to somehow identify the final station (again for each line that passes trough the selected station). For that I have to use the `LinePaths` table. Inside that table the data is grouped by `TimetableID`, so that the entries with the same value for the `TimetableID` are ordered by the `SN` value that represents the order in which the bus arrives to the stations (like this: `xxxxx, 1111, 3, 8:15, 8:20, 9999`) - this means that the bus that drives according to the timetable `1111` will arrive at `8:15` to the station with StationID `9999`, leave at `8:20`, and that station is the `3rd` one on this route (the `xxxxx` is the ID of the `LinePath`, and is not important for this query).

So, finally, my question is - how can I, using SQL, get the data in the following schema:

- `FinalStationName`,
- `Departure(from selected station)`,
- `Regime`.

Comment: What RDBMS is this?  SQL Server, MySQL, PostGres, oracle?

Comment: The database is on a server that uses SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way would be to have a new table with a TimetableID and the name of the final station, and join this table with the other ones, but if you really need to obtain the value without additional tables, you new to calculate the final station for each timetable. This query obtains the id of each timetable and the name of the last station

```
SELECT li.TimetableID, s.Name
FROM LinePaths li INNER JOIN
    (SELECT TimetableID, max(SN) as SN FROM LinePaths) as aux
ON aux.TimetableID = li.TimetableID AND aux.SN = li.SN
INNER JOIN Stations s
ON s.ID = li.StationID
```

and you could use it as a subquery and join it to your query via the TimetableID. Not the most efficient thing, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. I contacted my client and he said that the speed of execution is not the primary concern because these reports are done once in few months, so even few minutes of execution time would be acceptable

Comment: I managed to solve my problem with just a slightly adjusted query, so thanks a lot, I was really stuck with this one.

Comment: Just one more question - the max(SN) is not identical for each timetable (some lines have more stops than others) - how can I get the max(SN) for each timetable?

Comment: With my query you're already getting the max(SN) PER timetable. If you need the number, just change the "SELECT li.TimetableID, s.Name" for "SELECT li.TimetableID, s.Name, li.SN"